# QT5: Unable to set stylesheet properties using qss file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I'm currently working on an app and I'm unable to set global stylesheet. Here's the code I've been trying:

```
QFile file(":/dark.qss");
        file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        qApp->setStyleSheet(stream.readAll()); '''
```

and

```
 QFile f(":/dark.qss");

if (!f.exists())   {
    printf("Unable to set stylesheet, file not found\n");
}
else   {
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QTextStream ts(&f);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(ts.readAll());
}
```

For the first one I'm getting : 
*QIODevice::read \dark.qss device not open*

and for the second one 
*Unable to set stylesheet, file not found*

The second one used to work fine 2 weeks ago (build with msys2, mingw64, qt5.14.1.3), unfortunately, I had to reinstall mysys2 and since then this is not working anymore.

I tried to build using msys2 with all the packages I used 2 weeks ago (had to downgrade about 80 packages manually ) also straight from qt creator with no luck.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with msys. The most obvious reason is an incorrect project setup. Please make sure dark.qss is added into the resource (qrc) file under "/" prefix and the qrc file is added into RESOURCES in the pro file.

Also, there is a bug in qmake not adding newly added resources into the app sometimes. A full rebuild might help in this situation.

It would be great if you paste both the qrc and pro file here. A full build log could be very helpful as well.

Comment: So, following your advice looked again in the .pro file here's what I had: RESOURCES += dark.qrc and what seems to fix it is modifying it to RESOURCES += \ don't really know why the first version stopped working

Comment: @CiprianPetronelMacovei Cool! I'm sure the issue is with qmake. It's a known issue. Sometimes it doesn't recognize the pro file updates and doesn't re-generate make rules. The general solution is to do a full rebuild. By "full" I mean a truly full rebuild :) i.e. delete **the entire** build directory with all the generated build and object files (makefiles, .o/.obj, mocs, etc.) and compile from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your .pro file is missing RESOURCES variable with .qrc file name.

You can also try to execute *Clean* and *Run qmake* on your project before building.

Comment: The qrc file is added on the pro file... already tried a different stylesheet ( both qss and qrc files). As I said it used to work until I had to reinstall msys.